# Plot shift when tapping on legend's entry - CorePlot

Tags: ios, core-plot

I'm developing an app with CorePlot and encountering the problem.
I'm using `CPTLegendDelegate` to popup a setting panel for corresponding plot lines.

Problem is, when tapping on any legends entries, the plot shifts about 50 px and I want to stop it.

Attaching the image of the screen. The blue dashed line shows border of graph and cyan shows border of plotAreaFrame. Even the legend is outside of plotAreaFrame, plot shifts when legend is tapped.

When the legend was located at the bottom/centre. This problem doesn't happen.

If anyone can suggest the solution or work around, it'd be appreciated.
Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was using the delegate method `legend:legendEntryForPlot:touchUpAtIndex:` originally but after I changed it to `legend:legendEntryForPlot:touchDownAtIndex:`, the shift doesn't seem to happen.